# How to iterate a C# generic list in javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, generics, razor

Currently I have a button that fires **addMultipleToCart** - It is supposed to pass in this object that I created called **productids**

```
List<String> productids = new List<String>();
```

Here is how I register the onClick event:

```
 <a id="displayAddToCart" href="#" onclick="addMultipleToCart('@productids');return false;"
  role="button" class="btn primary btn-add-to-cart">Add To Cart</a>
```

When this event gets called, it is supposed loop through the list like so :

```
this.addMultipleToCart = function (products) {
        for (var i = 0, len = products.length; i < len; i++) {
            insite.productdetail.addToCartClick(products[i], '1', '');
        }
    };
```

However, when products gets passed through, it looks like the object isn't getting passed, but the name of the object type? It looks like this:

```
products = "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]"
```

So, when I loop through, I end up looping through the string

> "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]"

Which is obviously not what I want. How can I access my list using javascript?

Comment: use a JSON library to convert the list into an array.

Comment: @DanielA.White do you mean `JSON` when say `array`? :-)